# Mapping Entity Relationships with Inheritance in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am defining a class User which is a parent to my two other classes: Submitter and Assignee. User has all my attributes listed and Submitter and Assignee will just inherit all its attributes.  A submitter can submit many Requests.

The models I have coded look like this:

User

```
package com.merck.trackertest.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String isid;
    private String email;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String isid, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.isid = isid;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Submitter

```
package com.merck.trackertest.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Submitter extends User {


    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "submitter_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id"
    )
    private List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    public Submitter(String firstName, String lastName, String isid, String email) {
        super(firstName, lastName, isid, email);
    }

    public void addToList(Request request) {
        requests.add(request);
    }

    public void deleteFromList(Request request) {
        requests.remove(request);
    }    
}
```

Request

```
package com.merck.trackertest.models;



import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "requests")
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String receivedDate;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private String requestNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "submitter_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Submitter submitter;

    private String assigneeId;
    
    private String status;

    public Request(String receivedDate, String startDate, String requestNumber, String status) {
        this.receivedDate = receivedDate;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I have not modelled the Assignee table as of yet.

My concern is the table Submitter does not show anything but the id, is there a way to present the data with the id to the list of requests.  Would using @Embeddable and @Embedded make the most sense here, can I do that even though I have defined Request as an Entity.  What is the correct way of referencing a OneToMany Bidirectional relationship which uses Inheritance.

Table looks like the below which doesn't provide any useful information.

[image: Table in H2]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Submitter and Assignee tables created with all the cloumns from the user class, you have 2 choices

**Mapped super class :**

You need make the user class mapped super class by adding the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation and removing the `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations.

Classes having the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation won't be persisted in the database (no table created).

Entities extending this MappedSuperClass will inherit its properties.
In the database, this will correspond to one Sumbitter table with columns for the declared and inherited fields of the User class.

**Table per class strategy :**

The Table per Class strategy maps each entity to its table, which contains all the properties of the entity, including the ones inherited.

For this you need to modify the inheritance strategy annotation :

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear, the user class needs to be persisted as the user class will be actioned upon.  So submitter submits a request, an assignee handles the request, and users are the one that are being actioned on. Hope that clarifies, why I cannot use the above strategy

Comment: You can use table per class then. Just modify the @Inheritance(strategy) annotation on the User class and you're good to go.